# Is SQL Server Express Edition free?

Tags: licensing

Just a question... 
For an instance, I want to develop a payroll system for a business, Is it legal to use SQL Server Express Edition?

Comment: yes. is this a real question? No....

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes. YES. **YES!!!** Totally, absolutely **FREE** for anyone to use in development and production.

From the [relevant Microsoft web site](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/Default.aspx):

> Easy to get. **Free to use**.
>
> - Available **free for both development and deployment**.
> - Quickly build and deploy your database solution.
> - Backup and restore with ease.
> - Available with a graphical management tool, reporting capabilities, full-text search, and spatial support.
> - Ideal for building Web sites and apps, small scale LOB solutions or for
>     redistribution with ISV applications.

Comment: did you say free?

Comment: How about if I use the Visual Studio with this?

Comment: @yonan2236: it is **FREE** to use - whichever other tools you use doesn't matter

Comment: Wonder why they provide a free version, probably just to hook you in

Answer (score 11):

As found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.120%29.aspx), you can use SQL Server Express Edition in production environment but you have to consider some technical limitations:

- maximum of **1 processor, up to 4 cores allowed**
- maximum memory utilized (per instance of SQL Server Database Engine) **1GB**
- maximum relational Database size **10GB**

Comment: Hi, is there any limitation on the number of employees working in the organization to which our software product is delivered?