# Can SQL Server Express be used for free and on VM?

Tags: sql-server-express

I would like to ask whether SQL Server Express is free for commercial use?

I'd like to install it on a VM and use it for small-scale projects.
We've seen mixed information about the licensing of SQL express so I need to clarify.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is SQL Server Express Edition free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295231/is-sql-server-express-edition-free)

Comment: Licencing is explicitly off-topic on [so]. But yes it is free